# In Grover's algorithm how do we flip all Fourier transformed states *except* the 0th?

Tags: quantum-computer

According to [this source](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/courses/intro-mqc/current/lecture08_handout.pdf), Grover's algorithm works as follows:

1. Begin with uniform superposed state (i.e. Hadamard gate applied to |00000>)
2. Apply the Oracle (flip amplitude of state that matches search criterion)
3. Quantum Fourier Transform
4. Reverse the sign of all states except |0> which represents the mean (DC component of the QFT)
5. Inverse QFT
6. Goto step 2

I am curious as to how step 4 can be implemented, as it seems to alter a single state without affecting the others (or all states except for one - same thing). To do this, don't we need to know from within an individual state whether *this state* is the one to flip (as we did in step 2 by testing the search criterion)?

This may relate to my confusion over the QFT. To take a Fourier transform would imply the states are *ordered* in some fashion - what determines this order? And to apply step 4 implies knowing which state is the 0th state, which also appears to be a question of ordering.

Answer (score 2):

First, you surround the operation you want to do with NOT gates so that you want to negate the $|1111...1\rangle$ state. Then, inside the NOTs, you surround one of the qubits with Hadamard gates. This turns the operation you want from a many-controlled-Z into a many-controlled-NOT with that qubit as the target.

[image: From 0000 to ccccnot]

Now we have a classical problem: given fixed sized gates (e.g. CCNOTs / Toffolis), how do we implement NOTs with arbitrarily many controls? One way is to combine controls two at a time, storing the combined value on a clean ancilla, until we get down to two controls. Then we can use those two controls to toggle the intended target.

On a quantum computer it's important that we not generate any entangled garbage, so after doing that we must uncompute each of the merged controls.

[image: control folding]

That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: Your circuit appears to flip a single bit rather than a single state. My understanding was that QFT works over states not bits? or am I wrong there?

Comment: @SideshowBob The Hadamard operation converts between bit flips and phase flips. You can test the circuits in my [drag-and-drop quantum circuit simulator Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk) if you want to get a better feel for it.

Comment: Wow, so many questions here. Firstly, I don't understand your diagrams. According to the key on your (amazing!) simulator the thing in between the Hadamard gates is a probe, and so are the black dots. So nothing is being changed by the probes - where is the gate they control?

Comment: Secondly, I get that H converts between bit (|0> vs |1>) and phase (|0>+|1> vs |0>-|1>, renormalized) *for a single bit*. But the states of the circuit consist of entangled bits. So to invert a multi bit state such as |0010> we first have to identify it, then invert the phase, is that right? Is it correct that states are ordered by binary encoding, i.e. |0000> represents the mean amplitude (after QFT)?

Comment: @SideshowBob Actually that thing between the Hadamards is a NOT gate (an X gate). In the case where all the qubits with a black dot are ON, the qubit with the NOT gets toggled. The reason I use the same symbol (but smaller) for an X-axis control (the 'probe') is that in quantum computing [controls are kind of like operations](http://algassert.com/post/1706).